# Why should someone create a default move constructor but delete the move assignment operator?

Tags: c++, c++14

Today i came across a class with following layout (c++14)

```
class A {
//ctor  
A(..some specific parameter) :..init some members .. {}; 
//copy ctor
A(A const&) = delete;
//copy assign op
A& operator=(A const&) = delete;
//move operator
A(A&&) = default;
//move assign op
A& operator=(A&&) = delete;
//dtor
~A() = default;
}
```

What could be the intention behind creating a default move consructor but deleting the move-assignment operator?

And what is the impact/restrictions when using the class?

---

Update:
No I cannot share class details, however, the comments and answers are pointing to the right direction, it's all about ressource allocation and initialisation.

Thank you all soo much - you made my day!!!

Comment: A possible reason: If you have a `const` member variable then the move constructor can (must) initialize it but move assignment is not possible (as it might attempt to override the `const` member variable). (It would be the same with copy constructor vs. copy assignment.) I cannot see any `const` member var. in your exposed sample code. So, it's just a guess "into blue"...

Comment: You do so whenever you want an object to be constructible but not copyable

Comment: _impact/restrictions when using the class_: [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) is possible but assignment not. I.e. you can initialize a new instance moving the contents of an existing. (Concerning the suspected `const` member var. - it might result in degrading the `move` to a `copy` which is not necessarily an issue.) Once, an instance is initialized, you can delete or move it to another instance but nothing else. Resource management is a use case for this. (... makes sense if you spell out RAII.) ;-)

Comment: Could you tell us *where* you saw this class layout? That might help us figure out why it's written that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this means is that, once an object is created, some aspect of its value cannot later be changed. You can move from it of course, but once that's done, you can't move *back* to it.

Consider a `unique_ptr` that had this design. Such a pointer would allow you to transfer ownership, but only to a newly constructed `unique_ptr`. So basically, if you create a `unique_ptr`, that pointer object instance will either be managing that specific object, or it will manage nothing, because you moved from it earlier. It will never be managing a *different* object.